# How to access server variables from an update function?

Tags: couchdb

In particular I'm trying to access the doc_count (of the requested db), but I'd also like to know how to access the rest of the server, as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get database document's count from `req.info.doc_count` variable. See [Request object](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/json-structure.html#request-object) structure for more info. To easily inspect your own requests you may use dummy update function:

```
function(doc, req){
  return [null, {"json": req}]
}
```

However, this is the only server data that you can access from the update functions.